# Printing jTable content to one note using java

Tags: java, swing

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setJobName("jPanel2");
    job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
            if (pageNum > 0) {
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            jPanel2.paint(g2);`enter code here`
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });
```

I have used the above code to print the jPanel content. But i want to print the data present in jTable. How can i do that?

Comment: JTable has it's own printer interface, check the JavaDocs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public void printJavaComponent() {
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
job.setJobName("Print Java Component");

job.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pageFormat, int pageIndex) {
        if (pageIndex > 0) {
            return(NO_SUCH_PAGE);
        } else {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2d.translate(pageFormat.getImageableX(), 
            pageFormat.getImageableY());

            component_name_to_be_printed.paint(g2d);

            return(PAGE_EXISTS); 
        }
    }
});

if (job.printDialog()) {
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (PrinterException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage()); 
    }
}
```

}

Please try this code i think it helps you.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
PrintRequestAttributeSet set = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
set.add(OrientationRequested.LANDSCAPE);
resultFxTable.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, header, footer, false, set, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    //bill printing
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Bill");
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 750));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    JScrollPane jp = new JScrollPane();
    frame.add(jp);
    Container pane = frame.getContentPane();
    pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
    JLabel button;
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
    //natural height, maximum width
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    button = new JLabel("Qty");
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JLabel("Item");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JLabel("Amount");
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.weightx = 0.5;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 2;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JLabel("XYZ");
    button.setForeground(Color.red);
    button.setFont(button.getFont().deriveFont(22.0f));
    button.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 0;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JLabel("Ph.:4466266621");
    button.setForeground(Color.red);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(button, c);

    button = new JLabel("Reciept.: " + rn);
    button.setForeground(Color.red);
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 2;
    c.gridx = 2;
    c.gridy = 1;
    pane.add(button, c);

    JSeparator js = new JSeparator();
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    c.ipady = 40;      //make this component tall
    c.weightx = 0.0;
    c.gridwidth = 3;
    c.gridx = 0;
    c.gridy = 3;
    pane.add(js, c);
    try {
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM order_detail";
        rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
        while (rs.next()) {
            j = 0;
            button = new JLabel("" + rs.getInt("Quantity"));
            c.weightx = 0.0;
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.gridx = j++;
            c.gridy = i;
            pane.add(button, c);
            button = new JLabel(rs.getString("Name"));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 0.0;
            c.gridx = j++;
            c.gridy = i;
            pane.add(button, c);

            button = new JLabel("" + rs.getInt("cost"));
            c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
            c.weightx = 0.0;
            c.gridx = j++;
            c.gridy = i;
            pane.add(button, c);
            i++;
        }

        js = new JSeparator();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.ipady = 40;
        c.weightx = 0.0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = i++;
        pane.add(js, c);

        button = new JLabel("Total : " + summedval);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.gridx = 1;       //aligned with button 2
        c.gridy = i;       //third row
        c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
        c.weighty = 0.5;   //request any extra vertical space
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 0, 0, 0);  //top padding
        pane.add(button, c);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    job.setJobName("frame");
    job.setPrintable(new Printable() {
        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum) {
            if (pageNum > 0) {
                return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            frame.paint(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
    });
    boolean ok = job.printDialog();
    if (ok) {
        try {
            job.print();
        } catch (PrinterException ex) {

        }
    }
    frame.setVisible(false);
```